# Show column name for which I have Numeric Overflow

Tags: teradata

I am creating a table with a lot on columns, and i get the Numeric Overflow error. Is it possible to see for which column i have this error. I do not want to cast everything in there, or comment out chunks until i find it.

Thanks

Comment: When are you actually getting this error, on an insert?

Comment: No, when creating a table

Comment: Are you loading data from a flat file or copying from another table/set of tables?

Comment: The latter from  table/set of tables.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew's comment is important, so this answer is only related to creating a table, not an insert.
Currently, the only way to know which column is causing the error is to comment out until you find it.

You can help narrow the search by only focusing on numeric related fields.

Comment: Thanks, it is though a painful process commenting out chunks of code every time.